# On click, change content permanently; on hover, display new content briefly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am trying to set up functionality to display bio's for authors on a website. I would like to accomplish several things:

- Have the images appear with a border upon hover, and stay with the border upon click. (As of now, the border stays, but it's around the table cell, not around the image. I do not want to set a new class for image, since I am using this in wordpress and don't want to mess with the template and the classes already set for each image. I've attempted using an id, but only 'td' as the selector has worked for me).
- Have "hover-content" appear upon hover, but upon click, that bio will be the default bio that appears until another image is clicked. (But can still change when hovering over other images)

This is what I have accomplished thus far: https://jsfiddle.net/nsn3bpep/2/

```
var divContent = $("#content").html();
$("td").click(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find("#hover-content").html());
         $("td").removeClass('myClickState');
         $(this).addClass('myClickState');
    $(this).off('mouseleave');
});
$("td").hover(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find("#hover-content").html());
}, function () {
    $("#content").html(divContent);
});
```

The biggest issue I am having is with click and setting a default hover-content to be displayed when one image is selected. It seems to maintain whatever was most previously clicked and then hovered, not most previously clicked disregarding any hover motion.

Comment: Change `$(this).off('mouseleave');` to `divContent = $("#content").html();` You unsubscibe from the even and then never subscribe again, which provokes certain artefacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your style with jquery to the image directly (I know this is not the best practice) or change the order of your classes.

And store the value of `#content` everytime you click (remove `$(this).off('mouseleave');`):

```js
var divContent = $("#content").html();
$("td").click(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find(".hover-content").html());
        $("img[class*='wp-image-']").removeClass('myClickState');
        $(this).find('img[class*="wp-image-"]').addClass('myClickState');    
    divContent = $("#content").html();
});

$("td").hover(function () {
    $("#content").html($(this).find(".hover-content").html());
}, function () {
    $("#content").html(divContent);
});
```

```css
.hover-content {
    display: none;
}

 .container {
    display: inline;
}


td {
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img[class*="wp-image-"]:hover {
 display: block;
 margin: 1.2% auto 0;
 max-width: 98%;
 border: 3px solid #99888A;
}


img[class*="wp-image-"] {
 display: block;
 margin: 1.2% auto 0;
 max-width: 98%;
 border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.myClickState, .myHoverState {
    border: 3px solid #99888A !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-301" src="http://wesdeboer.com/files/2013/01/sample-4-150x150.jpg"  width="120" height="120" />
                <div class="hover-content">
<strong>image 1</strong>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-300" src="http://wesdeboer.com/files/2013/01/sample-4-150x150.jpg" width="120" height="120" />
                <div class="hover-content">
<strong>image 2</strong>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-302" src="http://wesdeboer.com/files/2013/01/sample-4-150x150.jpg"  width="120" height="120" />
                <div class="hover-content">
<strong>image 3</strong>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-414" src="http://wesdeboer.com/files/2013/01/sample-4-150x150.jpg"  width="120" height="120" />
                <div class="hover-content">
<strong>image 4</strong> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**EDITS** Toggle the class `myClickState` to the image, and add `!important` to the rule `border: 3px solid #99888A` inside `myClickState`.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help. Any doubt you can ask me ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field to store content div contents. Also use .myClickState img, .myHoverState img selector for image border in CSS. Check fiddle below for solution
 https://jsfiddle.net/nsn3bpep/5/

```
$("#content").html($(this).find("#hover-content").html());
```

Comment: Please provide more info to the OP. this only worked when you changed 2 css selectors. This answer is wrong because you don't tell this to the OP, and he could think you didn't change the css.